# How to achieve this concatenation in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` :-

| tray | bag | ball |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to add a column `Presence` in the dataframe `df` seperated by comma this way :-

| tray | bag | ball | Presence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | bag,ball |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | bag |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | tray,bag |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | ball |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | No Presence |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with mask - compare columns by `1` with columns names and separator, last replace empty string:

```
df['Presence'] = df.eq(1).dot(df.columns + ',').str[:-1].replace('','No Presence')
print (df)
   tray  bag  ball     Presence
0     0    1     1     bag,ball
1     0    1     0          bag
2     1    1     0     tray,bag
3     0    0     0  No Presence
```

EDIT: If use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for values before `_` add `expand=False` for avoid one column `DataFrame`:

```
print (df)
   tray_col  bag  ball
0         0    1     1
1         0    1     0
2         1    1     0
3         0    0     0

df['Presence'] = (df.eq(1)
                    .dot(df.columns.str.extract(r'^([^_]+)', expand=False) + ',')
                    .str[:-1].replace('','No Presence'))
print (df)
   tray_col  bag  ball     Presence
0         0    1     1     bag,ball
1         0    1     0          bag
2         1    1     0     tray,bag
3         0    0     0  No Presence
```

Comment: For rows that have 0s throughout, I want to print `No_Presence`,I have edited the code. How can we do that?

Comment: In my `df` I had columns like  `tray_col` so I modified your code this way `df.columns.str.extract(r'^([^_]+)') + ',').str[:-1]` but it does not seem to work. Could you advice what is wrong with this code

Comment: @Scope - then use `df.columns.str.extract(r'^([^_]+)', expand=False) + ','`